# How to upload a notebook to the Wolfram Cloud using Android app?

Tags: notebooks, wolfram-cloud

I am using the Wolfram Cloud app on Android and have received an email with a notebook attached. Using the Wolfram Cloud app I would like to load the notebook to work in it. I can save the notebook to the device. However, there only appears to be a create new option and no upload option.

How do I upload a notebook to the Wolfram Cloud using the Android app?

[image]

Comment: As far I know, with Wolfram Cloud in mobiles you can only create and open notebooks. The only way to upload them is with MMA  desktop, and maybe through a web navigator. As an alternativ, you can use Wolfram CDF Player for mobile (I do not know if existe for Android either, I have iOS).

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas That would be less than ideal. I don't see the why you would create a user experience where you need to leave the cloud app to upload to the cloud.

Comment: I agree. If anyone emailed to you the nb file, you could try to suggest him/her that shares it to you via Wolfram Cloud. I think you could have access to it in the menu > Shared with you

Comment: @Jose: Is this issue of uploading resolved by now? If so, could you let me know how to upload a NB to Cloud for someone else to use it for calculations? Thanks.